# How to set up "front page" documentation on PYPI for a project?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I would like to add basic documentation content to the front page of PYPI of my module like it's done, for example, here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2.

Right now the askbot download page has a default look and does not have much useful info, how can it be added? That is - which parts of the distribution package files/which file must be edited?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you take a look at : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/an_example_pypi_project

Also PyPI attempts to parse the "long_description" from your meta-data as ReStructuredText. You could use that to provide a good information rendering.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged in you can edit the "Description" section of your packages.

They use the reStructuredText syntax for the field so you can use that for formatting: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html